# Is it possible to disable the Application Menu on the Ribbon Control? (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

Is there a way to disable to Application Menu, the circle thing on the left hand corner, so the user can't click on it?

I have absolutely no use on that, and cannot think of anything I can use that, I can't find any options to disable it.

Please help

Many thanks

Answer (score 34):

I did something like this, and managed to remove the Application Menu. Do check if this is the way you wanted it to be.

```
<r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
    <r:RibbonApplicationMenu Visibility="Collapsed" >
    </r:RibbonApplicationMenu>
</r:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
```

Comment: Interesting that Microsoft's ribbon control allows this, yet the guidelines say that the Application Menu is required.  I just checked the Infragistics ribbon control and it also allows setting visibility to "Collapsed".  I'm wondering if I'm interpreting the license correctly.  Anyone???

Comment: Sigh, the licensing bit is extremely confusing....I mean, is it really I need to implement the full feature of the ribbon otherwise I cannot use it? I managed to disable it as well, but not sure if it is legal.

Comment: I don't think they have actually released version 1 of Ribbon control. Use of the beta version in production is not legal either. Plus they don't have any process of verification either- whether or not the implementation violates the license.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437144/wpf-ribbon-control-can-i-use-it-legally-now

Comment: That's what confuses me - is the Application Menu required only in the IMPLEMENTATION of the control, or do you have to USE IT in all applications that use a ribbon?

Some things are clear like: You HAVE to have a "Home" tab, and when the application starts, it HAS to be the selected tab (just like in Office 2007.)  But some other things... Kind of a guess game.

I'm using the Infragistics ribbon control which has been available for a while already - the free WPF ribbon wasn't even available in early beta back when we bought the Infragistics WPF controls (some excellent stuff in there.)

Comment: I just sent the OfficeUI licensing group an e-mail asking for some clarification on this.  I'll post here when I get an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that would go against the Microsoft license for using the ribbon interface.

Check it out here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809.aspx (dead)

([Archive from 2012-09-11](https://web.archive.org/web/20120911050644/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/office/aa973809.aspx))

> **Office UI licensing for developers**
>
> *Overview*
>
> The Office UI licensing program is designed for software developers
>   who wish to implement the Office UI as a software component and/or
>   incorporate the Office UI into their own applications.
>
> A license to use the Microsoft-claimed intellectual property in the
>   Office UI is required when the software developer does not use one of
>   the Microsoft-provided implementations of the UI that carries a
>   separate license (currently either the Microsoft Windows 7 API
>   implementation or the Microsoft WPF implementation in the .NET
>   framework 4).
>
> A license is also required when the software developer wishes to use
>   elements of the Office 2010 UI that are not provided by those other
>   implementations.
>
> *How to implement the Office UI in your own software*
>
> There are currently three primary categories of ways for a software
>   developer to implement the Office UI in their own application or
>   component.
>
> - Use the Microsoft Windows 7 Scenic Ribbon implementation
>
>   Details about the Scenic Ribbon can be found on the [MSDN Code Gallery](https://web.archive.org/web/20120911050644/http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ScenicRibbon).    Use of
>     the Scenic Ribbon implementation is governed by the Microsoft Windows
>     SDK EULA and does not require a developer to accept the terms of the
>     Office UI license on this site.
> - Use the Microsoft Ribbon for WPF Implementation
>
>   Details about the Microsoft Ribbon for WPF Implementation (delivered via MS Downloads)
>     can be found in the MSDN Library. Use of the Microsoft Ribbon for WPF
>     is governed by a EULA similar to that of the .NET Framework. This
>     release does not require developers to accept the terms of the Office
>     UI license on this site.
> - Use Microsoft Foundation Classes (MFC) Ribbon, build it yourself, or use a third-party component
>
>   All of the options in this category
>     require acceptance of the Office UI License terms on this site. The
>     additional benefits of this category include the ability to implement
>     across more platforms, the ability to use elements of the Office 2010
>     UI that are not incorporated in the other implementations, and the
>     ability to use a third-party component that may have other benefits to
>     you as a developer.
>
>   If you find this category appropriate you should read the materials
>     on this site, specifically the Office UI License and the Office UI
>     Design Guidelines. You may search the web for component vendors by
>     searching for terms like "Microsoft Ribbon component vendor".

But I don't have any use for it either, so I just put the "Exit" option in there.

---

**EDIT:**

It was confusing if the Application Menu required only in the IMPLEMENTATION of the control, or do you have to USE IT in all applications that use a ribbon?

Some things are clear like: You HAVE to have a "Home" tab, and when the application starts, it HAS to be the selected tab (just like in Office 2007.) But some other things... Kind of a guessing game.

I just sent the Office UI group at Microsoft  an e-mail asking for some clarification on this. Here's the answer: looks like the Application Menu is NOT optional:

> Thank you for submitting your question.  The design guidelines do
>   stipulate that the Application Menu is required and it is a critical
>   element of the Ribbon UI implementation.  Different control sets may
>   allow for the hiding or disabling of the UI element, but the
>   expectation is that your finished application will still contain an
>   Application Menu element (you may seek to implement it yourself as
>   part of your window frame, or through other means).

---

**EDIT:** The license has been retired:

https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/18329/what-is-the-status-of-microsoft-ribbon-licensing-as-of-2017

Comment: I try just put Exit option, but it looks extremely ugly with that, sigh, I guess I need to do that, hope that Microsoft won't sue me for that. There are too many gray areas on that license issues.

Comment: The link is expired. Is this license invalid in newer programs?

Comment: @Assimilater Here you go: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/18329/what-is-the-status-of-microsoft-ribbon-licensing-as-of-2017

Answer (score 3):

In to xaml file post the code:

```
<Ribbon ApplicationMenu="{x:Null}">
       <TabControl></TabControl>
</Ribbon>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.ultraToolbarsManager1.Office2007UICompatibility = false;
this.ultraToolbarsManager1.Ribbon.FileMenuStyle = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.FileMenuStyle.None;
```

Try this one. its Only used windows application form